# Android: Possible bug in DatePicker?

Tags: android, datepicker

I have been able to reproduce, in Android emulators 1.5, 1.6, 2.0 and 2.1, the following behaviour: copy text "241299999999999999" from any `EditText` view; go to any date picker (ex: Date & Time Settings) and paste that value as the year or month.

The application using the `DatePicker` crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
10-24 15:50:54.674: E/AndroidRuntime(1012): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(1012): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '241299999999999999' as integer
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:390)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:374)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:333)
at com.android.internal.widget.NumberPicker.getSelectedPos(NumberPicker.java:379)
at com.android.internal.widget.NumberPicker.access$1100(NumberPicker.java:37)
at com.android.internal.widget.NumberPicker$NumberRangeKeyListener.filter(NumberPicker.java:362)
at com.android.internal.widget.NumberPicker$NumberPickerInputFilter.filter(NumberPicker.java:316)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:417)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
at android.widget.TextView.onTextContextMenuItem(TextView.java:6932)
at android.widget.TextView$MenuHandler.onMenuItemClick(TextView.java:6853)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:133)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:813)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:120)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:884)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:283)
at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3132)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1620)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming integer takes 4 bytes, the maximum value it can take is

2^32 = 4,294,967,296.

you have given the value which is out of the range , in order to recognize it as an integer.

Comment: Absolutely, the logcat says "unable to parse '241299999999999999' as integer"!

Comment: I know it should not be able to recognize it as an Integer, but shouldn't it be protected against this case? I think crashing in this case is not the desired behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't happen for me; on my Samsung Fascinate (2.2), it won't even allow me to paste or enter in a number that large.

Comment: Yes, it seems like Google fixed the issue in Android 2.2

Comment: I should learn to read. :) You did stop at 2.1 in your post. I'll disappear now. :P